# Woo Commerce Fist Last Name Field restrict NUMBERS from being Used

Tags: woocommerce

I need to restrict the use of numbers in the Woo commerce check out fields for first and last name ..

and validate it contains only A-Z letter

any help would be amazing thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `functions.php`

```php
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', function ( $fields, $errors ) {

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $fields['billing_first_name'])) {
        $errors->add('billing_first_name', 'First name must contain only alphabetic characters');
    }

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $fields['billing_last_name'])) {
        $errors->add('billing_last_name', 'Last name must contain only alphabetic characters');
    }
}, 10, 2);
```